# Understanding an example for the Lemma preceding the proof of the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

my topology professor gave us an example to demonstrate how exactly a particular lemma that proceeds the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem works.

The lemma is:
*If $B\subset A$ and $f:A \to B$ is one-one, then there exists a function $h: A\to B,$ which is a one-one correspondence.*

Now the proof begins saying:
Take $B \subset A$ and suppose $B \not = A$. Recall that $A-B = \{a \in A| a \not \in B\}.$ Define

$$C = \bigcup_{n \geq 0} f^n (A-B),$$
where $f^0 = id_A$ and $f^k(x) = f(f^{k-1}(x)).$
(The whole proof should be able to be found here on page 5: https://pages.vassar.edu/mccleary/files/2011/04/FinalChapter1.pdf).

Anyways, the example my professor gave us was $A = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...\} = \mathbb{N}$ and $B = \{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10\} =2\mathbb{N}$, and let $f: A\to B$ be $f(x) = 6x$.

So I'm trying to understand this example and how it would lead to the result in the proof as a whole. I'm kind of confused however concerning the part $f^0 = id_A$. For this example, would $f^0 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...\}$ since $A = \mathbb{N}$? Or would it be $f^0 = \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ...\}$ since our definition of $C$ says $f^n(A-B)$ which would give us $f^n(\mathbb{N} - 2\mathbb{N}).$

Comment: You might find my [video](https://youtu.be/IkoKttTDuxE) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In the construction in the proof we *define* $f^0$ to be the identity function on $A$, $f^1 = f$, $f^2 = f \circ f$, $f^3 = f \circ f \circ f$, and so on.  So in the specific example, the functions are given by these formulas:

- $f^0(x) = x$
- $f^1(x) = 6x$
- $f^2(x) = f(f(x)) = f(6x) = 6*6x = 6^2x$
- $f^3(x) = f(f^2(x)) = f(6^2x) = 6*6^2x = 6^3x$

and so on.  Thus

- $f^0(A-B) = \{f^0(x) : x \in A-B\} = \{x : x \in A-B\} = A-B = \{1, 3, 5, 7, \cdots\}$
- $f^1(A-B) = \{f^1(x) : x \in A-B\} = \{6x : x \in A-B\} = \{6, 6*3, 6*5, 6*7, \ldots\}$
- $f^2(A-B) = \{f^2(x) : x \in A-B\} = \{6^2x : x \in A-B\} = \{6^2, 6^2*3, 6^2*5, 6^2*7, \ldots\}$
- $f^3(A-B) = \{f^3(x) : x \in A-B\} = \{6^3x : x \in A-B\} = \{6^3, 6^3*3, 6^3*5, 6^3*7, \ldots\}$

and so on.

Finally,

$C =\bigcup_{n \geq 0}f^n(A-B) =f^(0)(A-B) \cup f^1(A-B) \cup f^2(A-B) \cup f^3(A-B) \cup \cdots$,

so from the pattern we saw above, we get

$C = \{1, 3, 5, 7, \ldots, 6, 6*3, 6*5, 6*7, \ldots, 6^2, 6^2*3, 6^2*5, 6^2*7, \ldots, 6^3, 6^3*3, 6^3*5, 6^3*7, \ldots\}.$

That is, $C =\{6^nk : n \geq 0 \text{ and } k \text{ is odd}\}$.